# VSCode debugger refuses to attach to node process with no error or logs?

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, node-inspector

We're using node v18.3.0

I'm starting my nestjs app, inside a docker container, with this command `nest start -e \"node --inspect-brk\"`. Which gives the following output:

```
node@bfcdb32e737f:/opt/thallo/exchange-be$ npm run test:debug:wait

> exchange-be@0.0.1 test:debug:wait
> nest start -e "node --inspect-brk"

Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/c4d73a54-6165-4502-bcea-1fa4390db95c
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

So it looks like it's waiting for a debugger to attach - excellent!

I have forwarded port 9229 on the docker container, `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                                                  NAMES
bfcdb32e737f   exchange-be_exchange-be-uiapi   "tail -f /dev/null"      7 minutes ago   Up 7 minutes   0.0.0.0:3001->3001/tcp, :::3001->3001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9229->9229/tcp, :::9229->9229/tcp   exchange-be-uiapi
```

And I can telnet to that port from the host machine `telnet localhost 9229`:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

This is my launch.json:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach Exchange BE",
      "port": 9229,
      "request": "attach",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "type": "node",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "restart": true
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I launch the debugger I just get this little progress bar for a few seconds and then the debugger stops:
[image]

But there's no error log or anything so I have no idea how to fix this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For debugging a NodeJS application running a docker `127.0.0.1` interface wont reach the docker network try using `0.0.0.0`.

In the debug command at the package json change it to `nest start -e \"node --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229\"`

The `0.0.0.0` will tell the debugger to look at all available local network interfaces.

In the vscode debug configuration `"address": "0.0.0.0"` and it is recommended to use `"remoteRoot"` and `"localRoot"` directives for syncing the position of the current vscode work directory files to the files in the docker file system.

Comment: Thank you! This is fantastic. I had to set the remoteRoot but not the localRoot.

I am now running vscode in a devcontainer and the debugger can no longer connect - do you know what setup I need to allow that to work please?

Comment: What do you mean by “you are running the vscode in dev container” could you elaborate please

Comment: Yes, so basically instead of running vscode in the normal way I'm opening it in a devcontainer, which is a feature of vscode whereby the dev environment is running in a docker container which is managed by vscode. It basically means all devs are using the same version of node etc.. when running things inside the terminal in vscode. So we have .devcontainer folder which specifies the docker container information. This is the docs https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers

Comment: The answer to this was to add `"--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway"` to the devcontainer.json and change the launch.json to have `"address": "host.docker.internal",`